# BufferedReader reads incomplete file contents

Tags: java, android, json, url, bufferedreader

I'm trying to parse some JSON data that I'm receiving as response from a web url.

I'm getting the complete response, but when I read the response using BufferedReader, I get only partial data, I'm not able to read the entire contents of the response.

I've also tried writing the contents into a .txt file and again reading the contents from that file, but still it reads only partial dat, not the entire file contents.

Anyone has any solutions to this...

here is my code,

```
    package com.example.asynctest;

/*I have excluded the imports*/

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            new MyAsyncTask().execute();

        }


        class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void>{

            public String readBugzilla() {
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/rest/bug?assigned_to=lhenry@mozilla.com");
                try {
                  HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
                  StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
                  int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
                  if (statusCode == 200) {
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    InputStream content = entity.getContent();

/*I tried to Read the InputStream here, but it was incomplete, so I decided to write the contents of the inputstream into a text file, and then read the contents later on*/


                String fileName = "category.txt";
                File destinationFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), fileName);
                BufferedOutputStream buffer = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(destinationFile));
                byte byt[] = new byte[100000];
                int i;
                for (long l = 0L; (i = content.read(byt)) != -1; l += i ) {
                buffer.write(byt, 0, i);
                }
                buffer.close();

              //Read text from file
                File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null),"category.txt");

              StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();


              try {

                  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                  String line;

                  while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                      text.append(line);
                      Log.d("Law", "line is "+line);
                  }
                  br.close();
                  Log.d("Law","Text is "+text.toString());

              }
              catch (IOException e) {
                  //You'll need to add proper error handling here
                  Log.d("Law IO", e.toString());
              }
       } else {
                Log.e("Law", "Failed to download file");
              }
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return builder.toString();
          }

@Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String response = readBugzilla();
            Log.d("Law", "Response "+response);
            return null;
        }
```

I really tried all that I can, but can't find a solution to this problem, perhaps someone has used a better technique to solve this.

Comment: ...or perhaps it is a limitation of logcat ... check the results file on PC

Comment: Try `buffler.flush()` before closing it

Comment: How big is the file? How much(% of total) do you think it ends up reading?

Comment: @Neo The file is about 65 kb in size, but I get to read only about 15% of the entire contents.

Comment: @Selvin is right! I wrote the contents of the BufferedReader into a TextView and was able to view all of the JSON data. Thank you very much!!